# Tables automatically have same width

Tags: html, css

Ok, my problem is this, I had one master table and the `<td>`'s withing the table all aligned up pefectly and expanded nicley if header `<th>`'s wre beigger etc...

I had to break this table into 2 tables because I want the top portion to sort independent of the bottom section.  Problem now is I have to manually set the width of the `<td>`'s in the bottom table so it has the same width as the top table.  Is there a way for them to set automatically?

```
<table align="center" class="data_table" style="border-bottom-style: none;  margin-bottom: 0px;">

    <tr>
        <th>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>

<table align="center" class="data_table" style="border-top-style: none; margin-top: 0px;"> 

    <tr>
        <th colspan="9 title="Source of Repair (SOR) Remarks">SOR Remarks</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="845px" colspan="9">
            <textarea name="mcRemark" rows="7" cols="100" scrolling="auto">${mcRemark}</textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

This
`<td width="845px" colspan="9">`
is the size of the top table and could change....thats my problem

Answer (score 1):

They are now independent tables so the widths will be different.

You could use the data_table class to set the width of the cells in both tables to be the same.

Otherwise I'd imagine you could use javascript to grab th width of teh first table's cells and use those values to set the second table's cells. Bit messy though.

Answer (score 1):

Without going with a javascript/jQuery solution, no, there is no way to do this with simple HTML/CSS.  Rethink your solution by containing all data in one table, that way the TH's will dictate the column widths.

Answer (score 1):

You could put them back in the same table and then pick a row to divide them and style that row to make it invisible. Through border colors and background colors. Faux two tables.